# How to resolve SFErrorDomain Code=1 error

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, safari-extension

I am trying to making a blocker for Mac,I have follow these steps([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/SafariAppExtension_PG/CreatingandTestingYourFirstSafariAppExtension.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017319-CH11-SW1))

and then using this code

```
[SFContentBlockerManager reloadContentBlockerWithIdentifier:APP_EXTENSION_NAME completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {

            NSLog(@"%@",error);
 }];
```

It's print

> Error Domain=SFErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

I done googling and found that means of this error is

> "noExtensionFound error."

But I am not getting any solution for How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this error, what a silly mistake.

This error is coming because in new Xcode Content Blocker Extension comes with a different option next to safari extension option, and I chooses safari extension, and I am trying to make Content Blocker.So that's why "noExtensionFound error" is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Another potential issue is that you may have ticked the "Embed App Extensions" -> Copy Only when installing within the Build Phases

[image: Example of it ticked]

So make sure you keep that unticked in order for it to work